# Custom user defined types in Phantom Cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I am trying to create a custom UDT in phantom.

```
case class CreationTrack(source_ip: String, created_by: String, created_at: UUID)

abstract class Registrations extends CassandraTable[Registrations, CreationTrack] with RootConnector {
 object creation_details extends JsonColumn[CreationTrack](this){
    override def fromJson(obj: String): CreationTrack = {
      JsonParser.parse(obj).extract[CreationTrack]
    }
    override def toJson(obj: CreationTrack): String = {
      compactRender(Extraction.decompose(obj))
    }
  }
}
```

Input given:

```
CreationTrack("192.123.4.5","arun", UUIDs.timeBased())
```

But i am getting,

```
Invalid STRING constant{"source_ip":"192.123.4.5","created_by":"arun","created_at":{}}
```

I believe there is an issue with UUID type casting on json conversion. But i got stucked here. Any help? 
Thanks in advance!

PS: I know there is an option called @UDT is available in phantom-pro to resolve this issue. But i dont want to use the pro version here.

Comment: unfortunately you will not be able to use JSON columns as a replacement for UDTs, as JSON encodes everything as strings, so phantom-pro is your only bet. I'm happy to help you learn more about that if you email me.

Comment: @flavian Happy to connect with you on this. I want to try the pro version for UDTs. Your mail Id?

Answer (score 0):

This is a solved problem and there is a module available in phantom-pro specifically to address UDT/UDA/UDF support. Details on the website and GitHub documentation, just wanted this question answered in case future Googlers are looking for an answer.